# Have Jenkins (Cloudbees) only build on change in specific branch

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, cloudbees

I have a rails project hosted in BitBucket, and I am using CloudBees as a test and deploy environment.

I wrote a shell script in my Jenkins job that basically does everything for me. I have it triggered as a post-commit hook in BitBucket.

The problem is that currently, it does everything much too often, I only want this job to run when a commit has been made in my master branch. Now it builds also if no change was detected.

Is there a way to either:

- Have BitBucket hook only when a change is made to a specific branch?
- Have Jenkins abort an URL-triggered build if no changes were found?
- Have my shell script take care of it, by exiting in a way that tells Jenkins to discard and remove the build?

Answer (score 2):

Github plugin support this use case, as it uses incoming notification payload to detect the new commit, find impacted job(s) and trigger them. There's no such an option on BitBucket, as the trigger just run a specific job, without context information.

I think it's time for jenkins community to create a bitbucket plugin. Will investigate on this on my spare time.

Answer (score 1):

I created a somewhat cumbersome but nonetheless satisfying solution to this problem: a separate job that checks whether the deploy job should be triggered.

1. Create a separate checker job that does not check out any SCM project, can be triggered by URL and runs the deploy job after completion *only* if successful.
2. Use the following script, change

*Jenkins shell script*

```
[ $(git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:a/b.git master | cut -f1) == $(git ls-remote git@heroku.com:c.git master | cut -f1) ] && exit 1
exit 0
```

This compares the versions in SCM and on production without checking out any source code.

If you don't deploy using Git, you could write the current master hash to the file system on the production machine, and check its contents to see whether your build needs updating.